# How do I create a graphics banner with multiple lines in Rebol (can only create one line)?

Tags: rebol

This works:

```
view layout [
    box white 728x90 effect reduce [ 'gradient 0x1 sky] 
    font [align: 'center size: 40 color: red] "Your banner text"
]
```

But how do I add other lines ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Include a new line in your text:

```
view layout [
    box white 728x90 effect reduce [ 'gradient 0x1 sky] 
    font [align: 'center size: 40 color: red] "Your banner text^/on two lines"
]
```

If you aren't used to "escaping" characters in Rebol, it's pretty similar to doing so in C or Java or JavaScript or .....

This page in the Rebol Core Manual has all the details - http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-16.html#section-2.11

Comment: Oh that's a good answer, but I I forgot to say that I want different font for size and color.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work out how to get multiple lines with different font sizes and colours by reading this - http://www.rebol.com/how-to/subpanels.html

Comment: I still can't see how to create multiple lines as one could show only one panel at a time

Comment: May be this will help you get started:

>> banner-text: layout [                
[    text red "Your banner text"
[    text blue "More banner text"
[    ]
>> banner-text/color: none    ;; set transparent background
== none
>> banner-text/offset: 0x0     ;; set the offset from parent
== 0x0
>> banner-panel/pane: banner-text
>> view your-banner